# Floated Footer Disappears Below Preceding Floated Left and Right Columns?

Tags: css-float

I am making a responsive webpage with a header, 3 columns and a footer. Basic stuff as I understand it.

On a smartphone-sized display, the columns will each be 100% width and 100% view-height, and will displaying one below the other. Each is floated left.

As the screen size increases from a smartphone-size to a tablet-size, the layout will change to the first column displaying 100% width and height as before, but the two other columns sitting next to each other rather than below one another, each with 100% view-height but only 50% width.

**My issue is that the footer, which comes after the final column and is also floated left, is missing on the tablet layout, presumably because it is floating underneath the other columns somewhere. How do I get the footer to display below the last 2 columns rather than hiding underneath them?**

**The HTML:**

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="social_topbar">
        This is the social media bar fixed to the top of the screen.
    </div>

    <header>
    This is hero space.
    </header>   

    <main>

    <div id="column1">
        <div id="block1">This is a Souncloud Player.</div>
    </div>

    <div id="column2">
        <div id="block2">This is a Youtube Video.</div>
        <div id="block3">This is a Band Bio.</div>
    </div>

    <div id="column3">  
        <div id="block4">This is a Twitter Feed.</div>
        <div id="block5">This is a Contact Form.</div>
    </div>

    <footer>
        <h4>This is Footer</h4>
    </footer>

    </main>
</div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
/* ===== == = === SMARTPHONE 20em (320px) === = == ===== */

@media only screen and (min-width : 20em) {

#column1, #column2, #column3 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}

#block1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}

#block2, #block3, #block4, #block5 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50vh;
}

#footer {
width: 100%;
}
}

/* ===== == = === TABLET 48em (768px) === = == ===== */

@media only screen and (min-width : 48em) {

   #column2, #column3 {
    width: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
}

#column3 {
    margin-left: 50%;   
}

#block2, #block3, #block4, #block5 {    
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
}

#footer {
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
}
 }
```

Your time and expertise are very appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: no #footer{}, but footer{} in css.

Comment: and is there reason to use absolute positioning?

Comment: Thanks so much for the response! You're so right, the # was messing things up. However, now that I removed it the footer is floating on top of column 2 and 3 instead of below them?

Comment: I put position: absolute because I thought you needed to specify a position when floating a div.